# Packaging multiple jars using maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am new to maven. I want to package my java code so that, it can be run only by running a command java jar. 
My code uses 2 external jar files, 1 main java class, 1 property file and will output 1log file.

My POM :

```
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.ibm.mq.jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.4.0</version>
       </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
       </dependency>
     </dependencies>
```

How can i create a single jar file that could be run independently? 
Is it better to have this complied in a zip file? 
My property file needs to be changed by user. Where should I put my property file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, try one of the solutions in [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=1)

The property file must be *outside* the final jar so that the user can edit them.

Comment: How can I then specify the location of my property file?